# What kind of microorganism is this?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology, microscopy

It moves like a worm pretty much. I found it in a pretty big pond with brackish water. The water temperature was around 10 celsius.
[image]

[Here's a video of it moving](https://gfycat.com/OilyMaleCrustacean)

Comment: Could you add some more details? Where you found it, what kind of environment it lives in, size, etc?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now  I cannot really tell the name of it without knowing more of its properties and characteristic features, e.g. size. (I am afraid I am not very good with faces, especially of microorganism :D)

But I am 90% sure it might be an
[**Oligochaete**](http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/index.html?http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/pond/worm/oligo.html)

Comment: Please do not post guesses as answers and always provide references to your claims. I recommended deletion for your post as it does not fulfill [standards for good answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please feel free to edit accordingly to avoid deletion or - after possible deletion - give a new, well-researched and comprehensive answer. Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/37473)

Comment: @AlexDeLarge ok